# React + IE, не происходит перерисовка установленных стилей

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, internet-explorer

Доброго времени суток, коллеги!

Уже который день борюсь со следующей проблемой. Есть кусочек в таблице:

```
<th style="top: Xpx; min-width: Ypx">
  <div class="...">...</div>
</th>
```

В компоненте стили указываются инлайн и постоянно при скроллинге меняется свойство **top**. В DOM-дерево все попадает замечательно, никаких проблем, во всех браузерах все Ok, но вот именно в IE, <strike>как обычно,</strike> несмотря на то, что стили установились в разметке, пререрисовка не происходит.

Если, например, щелкнуть галочку в инспекторе на любое свойство, любого блока в дереве, то т.к. энивей вызывается перерисовка, то все становится на свои места.

---

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой, может я не заметил ответ на свой вопрос и уже на него отвечали?

Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Короче, всем спасибо, расходимся) Просто на будущее - не стоит смешивать табличные элементы и адекватное восприятие, все решается внутренним **< div />** с position